# How to add padding in a container without affecting the container above it in libgdx?

Tags: libgdx, padding

Let's say I have two continers c1,c2 with c1 being above c2. Now I want to push down c2 by 30 so I would do

> c2.padtop(30)

However this affects the orientation of c1. 
IS there any way in libgdx to pad one container without affecting the padding for container above?

Comment: How about changing the position of the container? Maybe use Marging instead? Use padding bottom at the c1. There should be different solutions for it. Just figure out which of it would fit in your szenario. The padding of the container above does not change! it has still same sizes and no distance to the other container. you simply change the overall position of the container for c1 and c2. For example you centered it. After padding the center point is different so it did move up

Answer (score 1):

Only if your alignment is CENTER will padding affect the placement of widgets.  If alignment is not your problem. You may want to try using .space() instead of .pad()